# WinAPI ListView Arrage Elements Horizontally

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to make a WinAPI ListView horizontal scroll only? The ListView is a list of icons `LVS_ICON`.

The below image shows a ListView that scrolls vertically. Is there a way to make it scroll/arrange elements horizontally?

[image]

```
CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, 0,  
          LVS_ICON | LVS_HORZ???,
          rc.left, rc.top,  
          rc.right, rc.bottom,
          hwnd, 0, hInst, 0);
```

Comment: What happens if you specify `WS_HSCROLL` but not `WS_VSCROLL`?

Comment: You can't change that. Only `LVS_LIST` will scroll horizontally, but without large icons. `WS_HSCROLL` has no effect either.